# How to use AlexNet with one channel

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, computer-vision, pytorch, torchvision

I am new to pytorch and had a problem with channels in AlexNet.
I am using it for a ‘gta san andreas self driving car’ project, I collected the dataset from a black and white image that has one channel and trying to train AlexNet using the script:

```
from AlexNetPytorch import*
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.utils.data
import numpy as np
import torch
from IPython.core.debugger import set_trace

AlexNet = AlexNet()

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(AlexNet.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

all_data = np.load('training_data.npy')
inputs= all_data[:,0]
labels= all_data[:,1]
inputs_tensors = torch.stack([torch.Tensor(i) for i in inputs])
labels_tensors = torch.stack([torch.Tensor(i) for i in labels])

data_set = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(inputs_tensors,labels_tensors)
data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(data_set, batch_size=3,shuffle=True, num_workers=2)




if __name__ == '__main__':
 for epoch in range(8):
  runing_loss = 0.0
  for i,data in enumerate(data_loader , 0):
     inputs= data[0]
     inputs = torch.FloatTensor(inputs)
     labels= data[1]
     labels = torch.FloatTensor(labels)
     optimizer.zero_grad()
     # set_trace()
     inputs = torch.unsqueeze(inputs, 1)
     outputs = AlexNet(inputs)
     loss = criterion(outputs , labels)
     loss.backward()
     optimizer.step()

     runing_loss +=loss.item()
     if i % 2000 == 1999:    # print every 2000 mini-batches
            print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' %
                  (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 2000))
            running_loss = 0.0
 print('finished')
```

I am using AlexNet from the link:
https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/models/alexnet.py

But changed line 18 from :

```
nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=11, stride=4, padding=2)
```

To :

```
nn.Conv2d(1, 64, kernel_size=11, stride=4, padding=2)
```

Because I am using only one channel in training images, but I get this error:

```
 File "training_script.py", line 44, in <module>
    outputs = AlexNet(inputs)
  File "C:\Users\Mukhtar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 477, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mukhtar\Documents\AI_projects\gta\AlexNetPytorch.py", line 34, in forward
    x = self.features(x)
  File "C:\Users\Mukhtar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 477, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mukhtar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\container.py", line 91, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "C:\Users\Mukhtar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 477, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mukhtar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\pooling.py", line 142, in forward
    self.return_indices)
  File "C:\Users\Mukhtar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 396, in max_pool2d
    ret = torch._C._nn.max_pool2d_with_indices(input, kernel_size, stride, padding, dilation, ceil_mode)
RuntimeError: Given input size: (256x1x1). Calculated output size: (256x0x0). Output size is too small at c:\programdata\miniconda3\conda-bld\pytorch-cpu_1532499824793\work\aten\src\thnn\generic/SpatialDilatedMaxPooling.c:67
```

I don't know what is wrong, is it wrong to change the channel size like this, and if it is wrong can you please lead me to a neural network that work with one channel , as I said I am a newbie in pytorch and I don't want to write the nn myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is not related to using gray-scale images instead of RGB. Your error is about the *spatial* dimensions of the input: while "forwarding" an input image through the net, its size (in feature space) became zero - this is the error you see. You can use [this nice guide](https://medium.com/mlreview/a-guide-to-receptive-field-arithmetic-for-convolutional-neural-networks-e0f514068807) to see what happens to the output size of each layer (conv/pooling) as a function of kernel size, stride and padding.
Alexnet expects its input images to be 224 by 224 pixels - make sure your inputs are of the same size.

Other things you overlooked:

- You are using Alexnet architecture, but you are initializing it to random weights instead of using pretrained weights (trained on imagenet). To get a *trained* copy of alexnet you'll need to instantiate the net like this

  ```
  AlexNet = alexnet(pretrained=True)
  ```
- Once you decide to use pretrained net, you cannot change its first layer from 3 input channels to three (the trained weight simply won't fit). The easiest fix is to make your input images "colorful" by simply repeating the single channel three times. See [`repeat()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.repeat) for more info.

Comment: yes this was the problem, thank you , because of you now the network now accept the input.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the size of my input, I gave it a (32x32) when I should have given it a (224x224) -I am new to AlexNet so I didn't know that it takes that size-.
I reshaped my images to (224x224) and now I am training the CNN.